# Connection lost when connect R to MySQL using collect

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, rmysql

I would like to use `dplyr` and `RMySQL` to work with my large data. There is no issues with `dplyr` code. The problem (I think) is about exporting data out of `MySQL` to `R`. My connection is dropped every time even I am using `n=Inf` in `collect`. Theoretically, my data should have more than 50K rows, but I can only get around 15K back. Any suggestions are appreciated.

#### Approach 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(RMySQL)

# Connect to a database and select a table 
my_db <- src_mysql(dbname='aermod_1', host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "")   
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, "db_table") 
out_summary_station_raw <- select(my_tbl, -c(X, Y, AVERAGE_CONC))
out_station_mean_local <- collect(out_summary_station_raw)
```

#### Approach 2: using `Pool`

```
library(pool)
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "aermod_1",
  host = "localhost",
  username = "root",
  password = ""
)

out_summary_station_raw <- src_pool(pool) %>% tbl("aermod_final") %>% select(-c(X, Y, AVERAGE_CONC))

out_station_mean_local <- collect(out_summary_station_raw, n = Inf)
```

#### Warning message (both approaches):

```
Warning messages:
1: In dbFetch(res, n) : error while fetching rows
2: Only first 15,549 results retrieved. Use n = Inf to retrieve all.
```

#### Update:

Checked log and it looks fine from the server side. For my example, the `slow-log` said `Query_time: 79.348351  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 15552  Rows_examined: 16449696`, but `collect` just could not retrieve the full data. I Am able to replicate the same move using `MySQL Bench`.

Comment: Are you sure this is an R problem and not a MySQL problem?

Comment: @ssdecontrol, it is possible. Or more precisely, how to configure a few MySQL parameters through R? For instance, I increased `DBMS connection read time out` in `Workbench`, but not sure what is the equivalent way through R.

Comment: I think the only way to configure the client-side timeout is to change the relevant option in your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, thanks for your suggestion. added `interactive_timeout = 60000
wait_timeout = 60000
net_read_timeout = 60000
connect_timeout = 60000` to `my.ini` and verified those variables are in use. But still could get full data...

Comment: OK, great. you also have to consider the _server_-side timeout, if any. Maybe you can check the debug output from `mysqld` for clues. Otherwise, this question doesn't seem answerable since I've never had this problem and don't know of a way to reproduce it easily.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, checked log and it looks fine from the server side. For my example, the `slow-log` said `Query_time: 79.348351  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 15552  Rows_examined: 16449696`, but `collect` just could not retrieve the full data. Am able to replicate similar activity in `MySQL bench`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the most recent RMySQL update, I noticed that I could not `collect()` data from large views, and I reported it as [an issue](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/190). Your problem might be related.

One thing to try is to roll back to the last version.

```
devtools::install_version("RMySQL", version = "0.10.9", 
                          repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That did fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed here 
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1968,
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/addb214812f2f45f189ad2061c96ea7920e4db7f/NEWS.md  and https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/addb214812f2f45f189ad2061c96ea7920e4db7fthis package issue seems to be addresed.

What  version of the dplyr package  are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just upgraded to 0.7.0 from 0.5.0 but still got the same error.  `attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pool_0.1.0     RMySQL_0.10.11 DBI_0.6-1      dplyr_0.7.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   assertthat_0.1 R6_2.2.1       tools_3.3.2    glue_1.0.0    
[6] tibble_1.3.3   Rcpp_0.12.9    rlang_0.1.1    dbplyr_1.0.0  `